# Folder hierarchy in packages - Turbo/Monorepo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, monorepo, turbo

Many articles and tutorials teach how to share components in monorepo projects.

But they show something in an unproductive way.

[image]

Share each component (package1, package2) separately in workspace. What I intend to do is export a complete package using atomic design, coming from a ui package only.

[image]

But when trying to do this this error is generated

[image]

I'm importing this way

```
import { Button } from 'ui/atoms'
```

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc --watch --outDIr dist",
    "build": "tsc --outDir dist",
    "lint": "eslint *.ts*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-custom": "workspace:*",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "tsconfig": "workspace:*",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  }
}
```

Using import from "ui" it works, that is, we would have to keep creating files like Button.tsx and importing them in the ui index and using them in the project, but it is inefficient, imagine thousands of components (atoms, molecules).

```
import * as React from "react";
export * from "./Button";
```

I think I'll have to share other config files, so I'll be willing to change the post and put them.

***App.tsx - Importing ui***

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { Button } from 'ui/atoms'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "main_",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.25",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "tsconfig":"workspace:*",
    "ui":"workspace:*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

***link to the repository***

[micro-frontend](https://github.com/ricardosc12/micro-frontend)

Ui library is being used in "apps/main_/src/App.tsx

Comment: How are you managing your dependencies? Are you using workspaces (e.g.: pnpm workspaces)?

Comment: yes, I used a base template from turbo.repo https://turbo.build/repo/docs

Comment: Before starting your app, have you built your ui library?

Comment: yes, using "dev": "tsc --watch --outDIr dist". Not using a structure with levels of folders works

Comment: I will be making the repository available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while without messing with monorepo, I came back these days and found the solution for it.

Let's go to the problem I reported, and considered unfeasible.
Many monorepo projects using Turbo using component sharing as follows.

```
//index.tsx
export { Avatar, AvatarGroup } from "./components/avatar";
export type { AvatarProps, AvatarGroupProps } from "./components/avatar";
export { Badge, UpgradeTeamsBadge } from "./components/badge";
export type { BadgeProps } from "./components/badge";
export { Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbContainer, BreadcrumbItem } from "./components/breadcrumb";
export { Button, LinkIconButton } from "./components/button";
export type { ButtonBaseProps, ButtonProps } from "./components/button";
export { ButtonGroup } from "./components/buttonGroup";
export {
  Checkbox,
  EmailField,
  EmailInput,
  FieldsetLegend,
  DropdownMenuLabel,
  Steps,
  WizardForm,
  SettingsToggle,
  Stepper,
  Switch,
} from "./components/form";
```

[image]

Realize that you have to keep importing all your components in the index, so that you can use them in other projects.

**Correction**

To resolve, just add the other files to eslint

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint *.ts* atoms/**"
  },
```

With that there will be no need to import all the components in the index, in fact, you don't even need to have it

[image]